# A problem on square matrices

Tags: matrices

> If $B,C$ are $n$ rowed square matrices and if $A=B+C, BC=CB, C^2=O$, then show that for every $n \in \mathbb N$,
>  $$A^{n+1}=B^n(B+(n+1)C)$$

I tried to prove it using mathematical induction. But I could not get $P(1)$ to be true.
$$P(1): A^2 = B(B+2C)$$
I couldn't equate them.

Please offer some assistance.
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A^2=(B+C)^2=B^2+BC+CB+C^2$$

Now use $CB=BC$ and $C^2=0$.

Comment: THanks I could prove it using mathematical induction

Answer (score 2):

Try P(0) it wll be easier. But P(1) should work too.

Comment: I need to use P(1). Can you show me how to get it true?

Comment: Well, N. S. answered it before me. But why do you need P(1)?? If you have P(0) and your mathematical induction, it will be also true for P(1) and P(2), P(3), ... P(n)

Comment: My text book states that first to prove p(1)is true, then assuming k to be true, prove that k+1 is true

Comment: If you start with P(1) it is proved for $n \geq 1$, if you start with P(0) it is proved for $n \geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is just the Binomial Theorem truncated to the first two terms, i.e.

$$ (B\!+\!C)^{n}\! = B^{n}\! + n B^{n-1} C + C^2(\cdots)\, \equiv\, B^n + n B^{n-1} C\ \pmod{C^2}$$

It is true in any ring where $\,\color{#c00}{BC = CB}.\,$ An inductive proof is easy. The base case $\,n= 0\,$ is true, being $\, 1 = 1.\,$ Suppose as inductive hypothesis that it is true for $\, n = k.\,$ The inductive step is

$$\begin{eqnarray}(B+C)^{k+1} &=\,& (B+C)^{k}(B+C)\\ &=\,& (B^k+kB^{k-1}C)(B+C)\quad {\rm by\ the\ induction\ hypothesis} \\ &=\,& B^{k+1}+ B^k C + kB^{k-1}\color{#c00}{CB} + kB^{k-1}C^2 \\  &=\,& B^{k+1}+(k\!+\!1) B^k C\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{CB = BC},\ \  C^2\equiv 0\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: thankyou your answer is correct